# Contacts have disappeared since iOS 7 update, and iCloud is not available

Tags: icloud, contacts, ios

After updating to iOS 7, all my contacts have disappeared and iCloud is grey in my settings, i.e. not live. I keep getting a notification asking for me to accept Terms and Conditions of iCloud, but when I click, it goes to the grey iCloud in settings. How can I sort this out?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings>General>Restrictions>Accounts, set this to Allow Changes.

This should render your grey iCloud settings useable again.

Answer (score 0):

Try and delete and add the iCloud account. 
System Preferences -> Internet Accounts -> Select the iCloud account and press the " - "

Next step, add the iCloud account by pressing the " + "